# Would chopping the first N digits of pi into N/x smaller integers would those appear statistically random?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For example, if I took the first billion digits of pi, in order, and then chopped those digits up into an array of, let's say 4 character chunks, would those 250M numbers appear random?  By "appear random" I mean when run through the standard statistical measures of statistical randomness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term you are looking for is "statistically random".

Of Kendall and Smith's original four tests for statistically random strings the closest to that you described would be the "poker test" which splits the string up into substrings of length five and tests that all the possible five-digit strings occur with uniform frequency.

If you look on the wiki page for statistical randomness you will find that, indeed, π exhibits a fair level of statistical randomness. However, it doesn't seem to out-perform known pseudo-random number generators. http://www.purdue.edu/uns/html4ever/2005/050426.Fischbach.pi.html

Answer (score 2):

It's not bad, actually!

For the $250,000,000$ $4$-digit numbers in the first billion digits of $\pi$ to the right of the decimal, one would expect $25,000$ of each number from $0000$ to $9999$ if the distribution were perfectly uniform.

After dusting off my Python skills and downloading the first billion digits of pi [here](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/contrib/pi/), I found that the most frequent four-digit number is $9048$, which occurs $25,623$ times.  The least frequent is $8885$, at a mere $24,361$ times.  The standard deviation of all $10,000$ frequencies is only $159$ and change.

But that's a peak-to-peak spread of only about $5$ percent.  Pretty darn uniform in my book, but your mileage may vary.